# Populating variableDefinitions with graphql-js parse

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am working on some backend graphQL code and using `parse` from [graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/) I cannot seem to populate the `variableDefinitions` field which remains an empty array.

Example:

```
parse(`{ x(id: $id) { id } }`)
```

I would expect $id to be recognized as a variable. It appears in the document tree as a variable but does not land in the `variableDefinitions`.

```
 "definitions": [
    {
      "kind": "OperationDefinition",
      "operation": "query",
      "variableDefinitions": [],
      "directives": [],
      "selectionSet": {
        "kind": "SelectionSet",
        "selections": [
          {
            "kind": "Field",
            "name": {
              "kind": "Name",
              "value": "x",
              "loc": {
                "start": 2,
                "end": 3
              }
            },
            "arguments": [
              {
                "kind": "Argument",
                "name": {
                  "kind": "Name",
                  "value": "id",
                  "loc": {
                    "start": 4,
                    "end": 6
                  }
                },
                "value": {
                  "kind": "Variable",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "id",
                    "loc": {
                      "start": 9,
                      "end": 11
                    }
                  },
                  "loc": {
                    "start": 8,
                    "end": 11
                  }
                },
                "loc": {
                  "start": 4,
                  "end": 11
                }
              }
            ],
            "directives": [],
            "selectionSet": {
              "kind": "SelectionSet",
              "selections": [
                {
                  "kind": "Field",
                  "name": {
                    "kind": "Name",
                    "value": "id",
                    "loc": {
                      "start": 16,
                      "end": 18
                    }
                  },
                  "arguments": [],
                  "directives": [],
                  "loc": {
                    "start": 16,
                    "end": 18
                  }
                }
              ],
              "loc": {
                "start": 14,
                "end": 20
              }
            },
            "loc": {
              "start": 2,
              "end": 20
            }
          }
        ],
        "loc": {
          "start": 0,
          "end": 23
        }
      },
      "loc": {
        "start": 0,
        "end": 23
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is not defining variables. The variable definition comes after the name of the query.

```
query myQuery($id: ID!) {
             ^^^^^^^^^^ definitions
  x(id: $id) { id }
   ^^^^^^^^^ arguments + variable references
}
```

Your current query would not be accepted by any GraphQL server as your variable `$id` is not defined. You can also leave out the name.

```js
parse(`query ($id: ID!){ x(id: $id) { id } }`)
```

Comment: oh my gosh how did i miss that!. Of course. I was working of some bad examples